# How to read data from USB using nodejs

Tags: node.js, usb

```
var usb = require('usb');
usb.on('attach', function(device) {
    console.log("usb attached" + device);
});
var devices = usb.getDeviceList();
console.log(devices);
var device = devices[0];
device.open();

device.interfaces[0].endpoints[0].transfer(64, function(error, data) {
      console.log(error, data); // null, <Buffer 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00
});

var buf = new Buffer([0xFF, 0x12, 0x01]);

device.interfaces[0].endpoints[1].transfer(buf, function(error) {
  console.log(error); // null 
});
```

I got result as { [Error: LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND] errno: -5 }
Please help me.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is Metioned in `usb` module's readme file that you need to install [zadig](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libwdi/files/zadig/) first on windows other wise you get that very specific error.